# How to remove empty array from json.I have no element in array , i want to remove array.Its nested array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to remove an empty array from JSON in MongoDB.I have multiple arrays in the object.

```
db.runCommand({
  update: "table",
  updates: [
    {
      q: {_id:  { $in: ['id1', 'id2']}},
      u: {
        $pull: { "a.b" : { "a.$[].b.$[].c" : { $exists: true, $size: 0 } }}
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

It only tell about empty array,but does not modify it.

Comment: if my answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted so that dev can figure that out and don't waste their time on solved problems.

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there but instead of $pull, you need to use $unset, as pull just remove the data from an array but unset will delete an array itself.

```
db.runCommand({
  update: "table",
  updates: [
    {
      q: {_id:  { $in: ['id1', 'id2']}},
      u: {
        $unset: { "a.b" : { "a.$[].b.$[].c" : { $exists: true, $size: 0 } }}
      }
    }
  ]
})
```